# Почему не коннектиться к phonegap?

Tags: phonegap

Всё делаю по мануалу: docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/1-install-phoneg...
1. Установил PhoneGap Desktop на компьютер
2. Установил PhoneGap Developer на телефон с Android
3. Создал простейшее приложение
4. Запускаю его

Но нет, выдаёт ошибки: "Unable to download archive from the server. Unable to properly connect to the server"

Что не так?

Comment: как вы конектитесь к серверу PhoneGap на локальной машине? должно быть нечто похожее http://joxi.ru/82QYg6ktl9Bg2d

Comment: Указывают адрес и порт, как в документации

Comment: а машина и телефон в одной сетке? Кстати, а сервер то запущен?

Comment: Нет... Телефон подключен к компьютеру через USB... Как их в сеть загнать, если нет вай-фай?

Comment: ммм, честно говоря как через USB я не владею информацией, у меня все через Wi-Fi. Уточните что через USB в вопросе, может кто знающий ответит